# Regex - match case sensitivity on replacement

Tags: ios, regex, case-sensitive

I'm trying to reduce the number of regex comparisons by doing a case sensitive replacement based on the source pattern.

For example, if I wanted to check for any occurrence of
'cl', 'co', 'ca', or 'cu' and replace this with 'kl', 'ko', 'ka' or 'ku' I would use these:

```
    pattern = "c([loau])" - replace with "k$1"
```

However do do the same with an uppercase 'C', I am duplicating the test using a capital C in the search because the replacement needs to start with a 'K'

```
    pattern = "C([loau])" - replace with "K$1"
```

I could of course find all occurrences of either using:

```
    pattern = "[Cc]([loau])"
```

The problem though is that then I'm not sure which case the replacement should be (upper or lower case 'k').  What would the form of a replacement string look like to selectively replace based on the case of the matching pattern?

Comment: how about use regex group ? split to upper and lower case 
like
(?<uppercase>[C]([loau]))|(?<lowercase>[c]([loau]))
and you can use GROUP matches to Replace 'K' or 'k'  .
best wishes :)

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at this.

Comment: Thanks - I had a look at this (http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) but don't quite follow what you propose?  I.e., what would the replacement look like?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're using a pattern like this:

```
pattern = (?<prefix>.*)(?<toChange>[Cc])(?<rest>[loau])(?<suffix>.*)
```

You can simply build a new string that would consist of (pseudo-code):

```
replacementString = ${prefix} + changedCharConvertedToString + ${rest} + ${suffix}
```

where `changedCharConvertedToString` is a captured `${toChange}` group converted to `char` with an 8 added and converted back to a string. This is because in ASCII chars have their respective decimal values assigned and the distance between the same small and capital letters is always the same. If you add 8 to a char `'C'`, you'll get a `'K'`. Similarly with a small `'c'`, you'll get a `'k'`. Google for "ASCII table" if you need other letter combinations.

Comment: Thanks - this is an interesting approach.  I'll look at this and see how it scales.